# Launch Google Earth website and auto load KML file?

Tags: kml, google-earth

I would like to launch the Google Earth website with a URL that would load a KML file from my PC.

Something like:

```
https://earth.google.com/web?kml=localfile.kml
```

I know I can bring up https://earth.google.com/web in my browser and then manually load a kml file. But I want to automate this load and not make the user have to go through the steps to manually load the kml file. Any way to automate this at all?

Comment: I don't understand the 'down vote' here. I certainly did hours of searching for this answer, I find it valuable/useful and I feel that my question was clear. Below you will see that I got this question answered in support.google.com. I hope this helps others.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From https://support.google.com/earth/thread/41761002?hl=en

Alas not at this time.

KML support in Google Earth Web is pretty basic, and users may need to manually enable it in settings first. 
... hopefully over time the support will mature.